# Move a file to under a directory using C#

Tags: c#, file, copy, directory, move

```
string str = "C:\\efe.txt";
string dir = "D:\\";
```

I want to move or copy "efe.txt" file under "D:\" directory. How can I do that.

thanks for your advice.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have mentioned you want to use `File.Move`, but given your input you'll also want to use `Path.Combine` and `Path.GetFileName`  like so

```
string str = "C:\\efe.txt";
string dir = "D:\\";
File.Move(str, Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileName(str)));
```

Answer (score 6):

From MSDN: *[How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)*:

```
// Simple synchronous file move operations with no user interface. 
public class SimpleFileMove
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Public\public\test.txt";
        string destinationFile = @"C:\Users\Public\private\test.txt";

        // To move a file or folder to a new location:
        System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

        // To move an entire directory. To programmatically modify or combine 
        // path strings, use the System.IO.Path class.
        System.IO.Directory.Move(@"C:\Users\Public\public\test\", @"C:\Users\Public\private");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

```
using System.IO;
...
string src = "C:\\efe.txt";
string dest = "D:\\efe.txt";
File.Move(src, dest);
```